# How to use the ThetaSketchOp function in pydruid

Tags: python, druid

I am querying a druid database using pydruid and want to calculate post-aggregate results where one aggregation is true and another is False.

I have been able to calculate the post-aggregate result using curl to POST a JSON format query to the druid database.

Using pydruid I have been able to calculate initial aggregations and a post-aggretation of the intersect of two aggregate groups. I have tried to find a way to use the ThetaSketchOp class for my purpose but without any success so far.

Here is my attempt so far at using the ThetaSketchOp class in pydruid:

```
result = query.groupby(
    datasource='datasource',
    granularity='all',
    intervals='2018-06-30/2018-08-30',
    filter=(
        (filters.Dimension('fruit') == 'apple') |
        (filters.Dimension('fruit') == 'orange') 
    ),    
    aggregations={
        'apple': aggregators.filtered(
            filters.Dimension('fruit') == 'apple',
            aggregators.thetasketch('person')),
        'orange': aggregators.filtered(
            (filters.Dimension('fruit') == 'orange'),
            aggregators.thetasketch('person')),
    },
    post_aggregations={
        'apple_&_orange': postaggregator.ThetaSketchEstimate(
                postaggregator.ThetaSketch('apple') &
                postaggregator.ThetaSketch('orange')                
        ),
        'apple_&_not_orange': postaggregator.ThetaSketchEstimate(
            postaggregator.ThetaSketchOp(
                fn='not', 
                fields=[
                    postaggregator.ThetaSketch('apple'),
                    postaggregator.ThetaSketch('orange')
                ],
                name='testing'
            )
        )
    }
)
```

Here is the json formatted query that produces the desired result when used to query the druid database:

```
{
"queryType": "groupBy",
  "dataSource": "datasource",
  "granularity": "ALL",
  "dimensions": [],
  "aggregations": [
    {
      "type" : "filtered",
      "filter" : {
        "type" : "selector",
        "dimension" : "fruit",
        "value" : "apple"
      },
      "aggregator" :     {
        "type": "thetaSketch", "name": "apple", "fieldName": "person"
      }
    },
    {
      "type" : "filtered",
      "filter" : {
        "type" : "selector",
        "dimension" : "fruit",
        "value" : "orange"
      },
      "aggregator" :     {
        "type": "thetaSketch", "name": "orange", "fieldName": "person"
      }
    }
  ],
  "postAggregations": [
    {
      "type": "thetaSketchEstimate",
      "name": "apple_&_orange",
      "field":
      {
        "type": "thetaSketchSetOp",
        "name": "final_unique_users_sketch",
        "func": "INTERSECT",
        "fields": [
          {
            "type": "fieldAccess",
            "fieldName": "apple"
          },
          {
            "type": "fieldAccess",
            "fieldName": "orange"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "thetaSketchEstimate",
      "name": "apple_&_not_orange",
      "field":
      {
        "type": "thetaSketchSetOp",
        "name": "final_unique_users_sketch",
        "func": "NOT",
        "fields": [
          {
            "type": "fieldAccess",
            "fieldName": "apple"
          },
          {
            "type": "fieldAccess",
            "fieldName": "orange"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "intervals": [ "2018-06-30T23:00:05.000Z/2019-07-01T17:00:05.000Z" ]
}
```

Thanks for reading. Please let me know if there is any other information I should supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work if you use the `!=` operator to create the `NOT` theta sketch op:

```
result = query.groupby(
    datasource='datasource',
    granularity='all',
    intervals='2018-06-30/2018-08-30',
    filter=(
        (filters.Dimension('fruit') == 'apple') |
        (filters.Dimension('fruit') == 'orange') 
    ),    
    aggregations={
        'apple': aggregators.filtered(
            filters.Dimension('fruit') == 'apple',
            aggregators.thetasketch('person')),
        'orange': aggregators.filtered(
            (filters.Dimension('fruit') == 'orange'),
            aggregators.thetasketch('person')),
    },
    post_aggregations={
        'apple_&_orange': postaggregator.ThetaSketchEstimate(
                postaggregator.ThetaSketch('apple') &
                postaggregator.ThetaSketch('orange')                
        ),
        'apple_&_not_orange': postaggregator.ThetaSketchEstimate(
                    postaggregator.ThetaSketch('apple') !=
                    postaggregator.ThetaSketch('orange')
            )
    }
)
```

(I found this by digging into the pydruid source code.)

Comment: Brilliant! Out of interest which part of the source code lead you to this answer? I tried to look through myself but could not find the solution.

Comment: [The `__ne__` method in the `ThetaSketchOp` class](https://github.com/druid-io/pydruid/blob/34be613d77611f6eb91e20e68b4ad8997f2bb16f/pydruid/utils/postaggregator.py#L179-L181). It looked like it would create something useful, and it worked when I tried it.

Comment: Right, I think I understand now. I must admit that I think the cause of my confusion was that I did not understand the dunder methods ```__or__```, ```__and__``` and ```__ne__```. Thanks for your follow up comments.